# pixel perfect image cause flicker smooth move fail rounding css transform or css transition

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a pixel perfect image to move around the screen.

But the image flickers, it's not smooth moving.

I have tried two methods:

`style="transform: translate(32, 0);"`

`style="transition: left 2s; left: 32px;"`

Both methods cause flickering. Please see the example, and fix it too.

http://jsfiddle.net/ut7pcneo/1/

Image:
[image: pixel perfect chip]

Note: see the yellow edges, that cause the flickering.

### Edit:

I am trying to clone a game, but the movement has a lag.

See the original game on html5 canvas running smoothly: http://playdosgamesonline.com/supaplex.html

See my version using dom: https://github.com/eguneys/supaplex

Comment: I can't see any flicker in Chrome

Comment: I see lots of flicker in Chrome.

Comment: @LGSon, How can I record a gif in chrome to upload here?

Comment: I made a change to your fiddle, doubled its size, does this also flicker? ... http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/ut7pcneo/2/

Comment: If Korgrue is right, then another test you can do is, change the yellow to one with green, one white and one red and see if they flicker as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yellow is not a pixel color. It is the result of varying intensities of Red and Blue pixels. If the refresh rate of your monitor is not sufficient, you will observe the switch from high intensity Red/Blue to off (black) causing a flicker during animation. Since your graphic alternates yellow and black, there is a ton of pixel switching going on and a low refresh rate is definitely going to cause a flicker.

The issue is likely not your code - but your monitor.

Comment: Perhaps some pixel dithering would help here?

Comment: @Korgrue, The original game is written in c++ shows no flicker on the same monitor, so it's a browser issue?

Comment: Possibly. Not sure what the performance hit would be to be honest (if any).

Comment: @user3995789

C++ is a compiled language. JS is interpreted at runtime. This could be enough to slow your animation rate low enough that the flicker becomes noticeable.

Comment: What about css transition gpu accelerated? @Korgrue

Comment: Pretty sure GPU accel is managed at the client level. Enabling it in your browser will likely help, but you cant guarantee other users will have it enabled. Do you have a different monitor (perhaps a laptop) to test the animation on to help determine if it is indeed the monitor or if it is just a JS animation issue.